# how change event display - Fullcalendar v5

Tags: laravel, vue.js, fullcalendar

I'm using vue-js laravel an fulcalendar v5.

How can I change the layout of the events in the 'timeGridWeek' view?

[image]

i would like it to look like dayGrid Month view

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should give us some code of what you already have. Nobody can help you based on pictures. How do you init FullCalendar? Do you import al of its dependencies?

Comment: You can't do what you want without creating a completely custom view. The view shows all events which occur at a specific time horizontally, that's just how it works - which means that the time slots occupy equal height and make the grid look correct.

Comment: Is it possible you should just have one "free" event which shows the number of free appointments at that time currently, and other one which shows all the currently booked appointment details (maybe in a popover to save space). Then you wouldn't have this cluttered view. Either that, or if the appointments are all with separate specific people you could consider using the Scheduler and Timeline view so the appointments are split into groups according each "resource" (i.e. person the appointment is with, perhaps).

Comment: I thought something similar my idea was to group the events that and show it in a modal with more details.