# FullCalendar React event stack in list timeGridWeek

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

Searching for hours for a proper solution for this problem.

Is there any way that events at the same block ( same hour of a day) will be stacked in a list (column) instead in a row ??

im using FullCalendar within React

Comment: Someone a few hours ago asked almost exactly the same thing - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63949292/how-change-event-display-fullcalendar-v5 for the question, and see my comment below it explaining why it's not possible, and it doesn't really make sense, and it can't be implemented without a lot of customisation.

Comment: @ADyson thanks! i was getting frustrated, so many open issues on this topic and they still didn't fix that bug.. do you know any alternative library i can use ?

Comment: I wouldn't say it is an issue really. It's a natural consequence of using a time-bound grid system - all events which start at the same time need to be shown in the same place on the time axis. Stacking them so they appear at different points on the time axis will make it look like they start at different times. It's not desirable. Maybe consider exactly why you think you want this, and then see if there's another way to present the information. If you explain your problem, maybe I can suggest something like I did in that other question.

Comment: Anyway no, I don't personally know of another calendar library which has as many features as fullCalendar or would fulfill the requirement you've given here